# Azure Purview Sources missing from register sources option (SAP, HIVE, S3, "Multiple Sources")

Tags: azure, azure-purview

Looking to register all the Data Sources in a subscription/account but the option for "Azure (Multiple Sources)" is missing. As are other sources (HIVE, SAP, AWS S3).

Why would this be the case?

[image: Image of Sources available to register]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, Azure Purview does not support (HIVE, SAP, AWS S3) as data sources.

Azure Purview supports the following data sources:

- SQL server on-premises
- Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1
- Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
- Azure Blob Storage
- Azure Data Explorer
- Azure SQL DB
- Azure SQL DB Managed Instance
- Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly SQL DW)
- Azure Cosmos DB
- Power BI

**Reference:** [Manage data sources in Azure Purview (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/manage-data-sources#:%7E:text=Azure%20Purview%20supports%20the%20following,Azure%20Data%20Lake%20Storage%20Gen1&text=Azure%20Synapse%20Analytics%20(formerly%20SQL%20DW))

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/932437-azure-purview

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Comment: I have similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73376832/1232087) for anyone's suggestions/comments