# Microsoft Purview - selecting sources type when registering

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account, azure-purview

We have created [Purview Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-create-and-manage-collections) based on Storage Accounts Types: `Azure Blob Storage`, `Azure Data Lakes`, `Azure General Purpose v2`. Our Collection names are:

1. Blob-Storage-Collection
2. Data-Lake-Collection
3. General-Purpose-v2-Collection

For each collection when we try to register a source of the above type, we get the following screen to select source type. For Blob Storage account, we select `Azure Blob Storage` (shown on top row of the image below), for our Data Lakes account, we select `Azure Data Lake Gen2` (shown in third row of the image):

**Question**: For our `General Purpose v2` storage account, which source type should we be selecting from the image below? We don't see a source type of `General Purpose v2` to select from.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

•   **`The sources that you are trying to make a collection of are the types of various resource services available in the storage account, i.e., Blob storage, Data Lake Gen2, File share, etc. But the source type that you want to make a collection of is a type of storage account and not the inherent storage services that can be hosted on it. Thus accordingly, a collection of the source type for the type of storage account cannot be created in Microsoft Purview. In fact, if you check the available sources of purview collections in the Microsoft Purview portal, you can find out that they all are related to various azure resource providers registered in Azure, i.e., ‘Microsoft.DataLakeStore, Microsoft.DBforMySQL, etc.’. Thus, you can find sources according to the available resource providers in Azure for making a purview collection, not according to the type of that resource available.`**

For more information, kindly refer to the below documentation link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/microsoft-purview-connector-overview***